# PHP logout for next script

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with a log out script.  I am trying to destroy the session or kill the cookie but it won't go away.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        // Connect to the database
        $dbc = mysqli_connect(DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPASS, DBNAME);

        if ($dbc == null) {
            $error_msg = '<br/>EROARE: conexiunea la baza de date a esuat<br/>';
        }
        $error_msg = 'succes<br/>';

        // Grab the user-entered log-in data
        $user_username = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['username']));
        $user_username = PREG_REPLACE("/[^0-9a-zA-Z.-@_]/i", '', $user_username);
        $user_password = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['password']));
        $user_password = PREG_REPLACE("/[^0-9a-zA-Z]/i", '', $user_password);

        if (!empty($user_username) && !empty($user_password))
        {
            $query = "SELECT * FROM Admin WHERE username = '$user_username' AND password = SHA('$user_password')";
            $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
            if (mysqli_num_rows($data) == 1) {
                // The log-in is OK so set the user ID and username session vars (and cookies), and redirect to the home page
                $row = mysqli_fetch_array($data);
                $_SESSION['admin_id'] = $row['id_client'];
                $_SESSION['admin'] = $row['username'];
                setcookie('id_admin', $row['id_admin'], time() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 2));    // expires in 30 days

                $home_url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '/admin/index.php?admin='.$row['id_admin'].'&cat=index';
                header('Location: ' . $home_url);

                //==================LOGGING THE INFORMATION
                $fp = @fopen ($jurnal, "a");
                if ($fp == NULL) {
                    echo 'EROARE - nu a fost posibila deschiderea fisierului jurnal!';
                    exit();
                }
                //exclusive lock
                lock ($fp);
                //Writing information into the index_upload file
                $submitdate = date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');
                $utilizator = $_SESSION['username'];
                $adresa = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
                fwrite ($fp, "========================================\r\n");
                fwrite ($fp, "LOGIN OK\r\n");
                fwrite ($fp, "Utilizator: $utilizator\r\n");
                fwrite ($fp, "Conexiune de la adresa IP: $adresa\r\n");
                fwrite ($fp, "Data: $submitdate\r\n");
                fwrite ($fp, "\r\n");
                // Unlock the file, this is the same as flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
                unlock ($fp);
                @fclose ($fp);
                /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


            }
            else {

            }
        }
        else {
            // The username/password are incorrect so set an error message
            $error_msg = 'EROARE: pentru autentificare aveti nevoie de un nume de utilizator si o parola valide!';
        }
    }
    else {
        // The username/password weren't entered so set an error message
        $error_msg = 'EROARE: pentru a va putea autentifica in sistem, va rugam introduceti un nume de utilizator si o parola!';
    }
}
```

I tryed this:

```
<?
session_start();
session_unset();
session_destroy();

header("location:home.php");
exit();
?>
```

and this:

```
<?php
    setcookie('id_admin', '', time()-60*60*24*2);
?>
```

Comment: Where do you call logout from? Any warnings on server error.log?

Comment: The only reason will be short open tag that you used here: `<?` you can change it to `<?php` or test posted code in my answer

Answer (score 0):

According to PHP Manual for [session_destroy()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php) the following code should destroy $_SESSION:

```
<?php
// Initialize the session.
// If you are using session_name("something"), don't forget it now!
session_start();

// Unset all of the session variables.
$_SESSION = array();

// If it's desired to kill the session, also delete the session cookie.
// Note: This will destroy the session, and not just the session data!
if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
        $params["path"], $params["domain"],
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
    );
}

// Finally, destroy the session.
session_destroy();
?>
```

Comment: i tested this, still cookie remains setted

Comment: you can expire the cookie as you did, this code is just for session

Comment: i did, cookie is still there:|